# How to connect python to Snowflake using SSO (sqlalchemy)?

Tags: python, single-sign-on, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, google-colaboratory, okta

I recently had to enable SSO with Okta and had a few python projects I was running in Google Colab.

I am trying to redesign the connection string but can't seem to get it right.

This was my initial connection string before SSO:

```
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(URL(
    account = acc,
    user = usr,
    password = psw,
    warehouse = whs,
    role = rol
))
engine.connect()
```

This is what I found from research it should be with SSO:

```
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(URL(
    account = acc,
    user = usr,
    password = psw,
    warehouse = whs,
    role = rol
),
connect_args={
        'authenticator': 'https://myokta.okta.com/',
        }
)
engine.connect()
```

I tried that but I am getting this error:
[image]

I also tried using `{'authenticator': 'externalbrowser'}` but because I am in Google Colab I get an error stating `Unable to open a browser in this environment.`.

The Web UI is working for the same user so it's just in Colab that I am having this issue.

How should I go about to connect?

**EDIT:**
So after doing some research I found that because we have MFA enabled this would not work. Is it possible to then use:

```
engine = create_engine(URL(
    account = acc,
    user = usr,
    warehouse = whs,
    role = rol,
    authenticator = 'externalbrowser'
))
engine = engine.connect()
```

And have the `externalbrowser` be an iframe in the same notebook?

Comment: How does your **acc** value looks like? It should only be the account name + region if needed, not the entire URL.

Comment: yes I only have the account name in

Comment: The screenshot you provided shows the expected URL of your Snowflake account vs what is provided (post back: **/login/cert**). Can you enable logging using this [article](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-generate-log-file-on-Snowflake-connectors#python) and see what the log shows?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've collected the logs and seems it is the same as in this github [issue](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/663). It seems it is the same problem too. We have MFA enabled on Okta so I guess this use case will not be possible. In this case, is there a way to allow colab to open a new tab to sign in and return?

Comment: Google Colab runs on Google servers, that's why you can't open a browser. You can inject Javascript code to run your local browser probably but that's not going to solve your issue I believe. Are you forced to using only SSO or you can use other authentication methods as well ?

Comment: yes, we were forced to make this change to SSO for security reasons and can only use this method. I'm trying to see if I can use `display(Javascript('window.open("{url}");'.format(url=url)))` somehow to authenticate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution. When running `engine.connect()` with `authenticator='externalbrowser'` and Google Collab cannot open a separate tab, it will provide a manual link, which, when clicked, opens another tab pointing to `localhost` URL with a token as a param. I then copy this URL and when going back to the notebook, I paste this URL to the input box opened in the cell.